# How to repair a thin cut in vinyl sheet flooring

Tags: repair, flooring, vinyl

We moved into a new build home in June and over the past weekend my Wife saw this cut/slice in the sheet vinyl flooring near a room doorway.

Despite how it looks in the photo, it's almost impossible to see it unless the light and angle are just right, and viewing from a standing position. I'd like to know the best way to go about gluing it back to avoid making it larger, or creating a larger rip in the vinyl.

What adhesive do I require?
What can I place over the cut while it's drying that won't stick?

Comment: Please post that photo, see the Edit link and the mountain icon.

Comment: Waxed paper is often a good product to keep things from sticking to glue.

Comment: For materials, just look online, e.g., https://www.homedepot.com/s/vinyl%20flooring%20repair

Comment: I can't see the cut, but clear nail polish drizzled into a small cut then wiped clean can really help hide a seam.